# Repeat string in angular template without any tags

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

Is it not possible in angular templates to repeat an array in DOM without using any html tags.

```
//like
<!-- required output -->
<div class="names">
name1 name2 name3 name4
</div>

//expected syntax
<ng-repeat item in items>
{{item.name}}&nbsp;
</ng-repeat>
```

Comment: What does that achieve since you can get similar display using tags such as span?

Comment: @kubuntu I didn't wanted to add any tags. Was just curious if its achievable or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i didnt use `ng-repeat` instead i used `foreach`

here is the working [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/3RxtBjMFgri4EigrkNzE?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = ["simon", "joy","dona", "divya"];
  $scope.names = function (argument) {
    var allNames = "";
    angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item) {
      allNames = allNames + item + "  ";
    });
    return allNames;
  };
});



<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <div>{{names()}}</div>
</body>
```

Comment: or else u can use ng-repeat names in span

Comment: Yeah I can do it by spans but I wanted to do without any extra tags. Is there no other way like in other templating engines like handlebars -- `{{#each}}` ?

Comment: give me a tick. for the correct answer. hope u got answer